# subgit commit git -> svn also commits tip (trunk/)

Tags: git, svn, commit, subgit

Moving our VCS in-house and migrating from svn to git.  Have set up GitLab CE and subgit (whilst migrating all users over to git). All seems to be working fine (including authors translation) however when committing a file to git the resultant svn commit is:

```
/trunk
/trunk/path/to/committed.file
```

where by the git commit is just:

```
/trunk/path/to/committed.file
```

Is there a way to eliminate the

```
/trunk
```

from the svn commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use subgit in local mode, not in remote mode.
Read more about the "issue" here: https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-839

Comment: Thanks for that. From reading this is only possible if you have access to the locally hosted SVN repo, is my understang correct?

Comment: Cool, we have the same understanding.  Unfortunately I do not have access to the local repo. Marking as answer.